# Python on SublimeText 3 error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, sublimetext3

I'm working on Python 3, SublimeText 3. When I try to build it just sends me an error like this:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1][shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\MIGUEL\Desktop\name.py"][dir: C:\Users\MIGUEL\Desktop][path: C:\Python;C:\Python\DLLs;C:\Python\Doc;C:\Python\include;C:\Python\Lib;C:\Python\libs;C:\Python\Scripts;C:\Python\tcl;C:\Python\Tools;C:\;C:\Python\;C:\Python\Scripts\;]
```

When I start SublimeText3 I go to tools -> SublimeREPL -> Python -> Python, I save the file as name.py in my desktop. Then when i try to build the file, it always gives me that error. In my PC Python is installed in C:\Python, so I've added all the files inside it to the path in case that was the problem, but it seems like it is not. I don´t even have to write anything in name.py, it always gives me the same error.

I am just starting with both Python and SublimeText and I don´t know what else to try. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, you have an empty file `name.py` and try to run this through Sublime Text? Then you get the mentioned error?

Comment: `SyntaxError` means what it says: your file `name.py` contains something that the interpreter reckons is not valid Python (and on this matter the interpreter is *always right*). Unless you show us the code with the error we can't point out where it is. Edit your question to include it.

Comment: Exactly, it always gives me that same error, no matter the code. I can leave the file completely on blank or write 2+2 and it gives me the error.